# The solution for the all-pair shortest path problem on unweighted and undirected graph

Tags: graphs, shortest-path

The multi-source shortest path problem for unweighted and undirected graph is as follows: Given an unweighted and undirected graph, find the length of the shortest path between any pair of vertexes.

A straightforward method is to use BFS starting from each vertex, as the time complexity of BFS is *O*(*V*+*E*), the total time consumption is *O*(*V*(*V*+*E*)). My problem is: **Are there other algorithms for the problem with better time complexity?**

Comment: I assume that you have a designated set of vertices $S \subseteq V$, and you are interested in the minimum distance between pair of vertices in $S$. Can you efficiently check if the distance is 1? If it's not, can you efficiently check if it's 2? Can you generalize for larger distances?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/58198/14578

Comment: The title says "all-pair" but the body says "multi-source".  Please [edit] to make them consistent.

Answer (score 2):

[This paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022000085710781) shows how to solve the problem in time $O(n^{\omega} \log n)$, where $\omega < 2.372$ is the [matrix multiplication exponent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_of_matrix_multiplication).

This means that you have a better algorithm than repeated BFS when $|E|$ is asymptotically larger than $ \frac{n^{w-1}}{\log n}$, for example when $|E| = \Omega(n^{1.372})$.